# Data becomes a function when passed into redux function

Tags: javascript, redux

I am passing data into an imported function which is to be used with a dispatch. When I pass this through and console log 'data' in the console in the function it is displaying this:

[image]

The functions are here:

Initial function:

```
const onAdditionalDetails = async state => {
console.log('state.data in onAddtionalDetails', state.data);
console.log('onAdditionalDetails');
const response = await submit3dsAuth(state.data, props.basePath);
// console.log('response in onAddionalDetails', response);
// console.log('state in onAdditionalDetails', state);
// console.log('state.data.details', state.data.details);
// console.log('response in submitAuthResults', response);
if (response.resultCode === 'Authorised') {
  console.log('card payment is Authorised');
  props.presentSuccessfulAuthenticatedOrder(props.paymentsConfig, response);
}
console.log('card has been refused');
console.log('response in failed order:', response.data);
props.presentFailedAuthenticatedOrder(response.data);
 };
```

Function the data is being passed to:

```
export const presentFailedAuthenticatedOrder = data => async (
 dispatch,
 getState
  ) => {
 console.log('doing presentFailedAuthenticatedOrder {');
 console.log('data', data);
 const state = getState();
 // console.log('requestPayload', requestPayload);
 dispatch(
    apiLogToServer(
  `3DS Authentication has failed for bag '${state.bag.id}' due to 
${data.refusualReason}`
  )
 );

 dispatch(confirmOrderFailure(data.data.refusualReason));
  };
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're directly calling `props.presentFailedAuthenticatedOrder`? Does it get wrapped somewhere? With your example code, it's defined as if requiring to be called like `presentFailedAuthenticatedOrder(data)(dispatch, getState)` get in your initial function you're calling it differently.

Comment: I am calling this from a mapDispatchToProps function

Comment: Then I'd suggest re-reading the documentation. I'd guess that your `data` parameter is actually the passed `dispatch` function.

Comment: Sorted. Your advice made me track back the code and I was passing in the function instead of the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorted. I tracked back the code and I was passing in the function instead of the data. Thanks!